# Websites with RAW conversion contests?

Tags: post-processing, raw, education

Many years ago, back in the days when I didn't own a DSLR, I found some website which regularly posted random RAW photos for contestants to convert/develop (or whatever it is called in English). Everybody posted his result and then there was a voting. I was in awe for how well people were producing different moods and different accents using the very same raw photo. Unfortunately, either this website doesn't exist anymore, or I'm unable to find it.

Today, I'd like to show something similar to a fellow photo enthusiast, to get him hooked on the topic of raw conversion. However, it seems that I'm lacking the talent to create a whole collection of sufficiently diverse conversions of the same raw photo on my own. Also, my Google-fu was only good enough to discover some Australia-themed website with relatively boring raw photos and little inspiring contest entries.

Can you recommend a website with good raw conversion contests that is fit for the purpose described above? A bonus would be if they have some special affiliation with free software raw converters like RawTherapee or Darktable.

Comment: http://www.astronomyforum.net/astrophotography-image-processing-forum/ - they make regular Astrophotography Processing Challenges - but that's very specialized, processing astrophotography differs from regular photos, though feel free to try it out.

Comment: I would love to see one of these and the results. Sounds fun!

Comment: I don't think this is within the scope of the »no shopping recommendations« rule – there is no request for a product or service. It is about educational resources in shape of some special kind of forums, many of which can last for decades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the answer is, in fact, in your question!
There are RAW conversion contests on RawTherapee.
They call it "PlayRaw", and they do a monthly competition.

Here is the forum page: [PLAY RAW competitions](http://rawtherapee.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=11&sid=7aa4d341f7ba83ad641d86717c1f98bc)

Comment: Read the rules on that site and you will see you are only allowed to use their specific software for post-processing.  That makes it inapplicable for most of us.

Comment: "A bonus would be if they have some special affiliation with free software raw converters like RawTherapee or Darktable." Now, while you (and me) won't find that very appealing, this is useful to virtually anyone who hasn't bought into Lightroom or Aperture or other commercial converter.

Answer (score 1):

Jared Polin does this [here](http://froknowsphoto.com/tag/raw-edit/). He will discuss it in his youtube video-cast. That makes it a competition with a one-man jury ;)